# Performance testing xml over TCP using JMeter

Tags: xml, tcp, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am new to Jmeter and want to test one XML request over TCP.

How can I achieve that. I search for any help but did not get that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search for ["JMeter TCPSampler"](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler).
You will find several questions on Stackoverflow as well as a quite comprehensive blog post: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter/

This TCP Sampler can send arbitrary text to the server, however, the challenge is how to determine the end of a response message.
There are a few options available, e.g. based on message length prefix (see [LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl.html)), or a unique end character (see [TCPClientImpl](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/tcp/sampler/TCPClientImpl.html)).

However, if none of those work, you may want to implement a custom TCPClient class that could for example detect the closing tag of your XML response.

Answer (score 0):

There are following options:

1. Use [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) which comes with JMeter
2. Use [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) plugin (the TCP Sampler doesn't measure Latency and you might be interested in this metric as well)
3. Implement your own request using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy language if above options are not applicable for any reason